# In Javascript, make the content wrap, and some of them wrap an extra line

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the instruction I did not use to add newlines.The picture shows what it looks like now.

```
console.log(path2gcode(svg));
```

[image]

This is the instruction I use to add newlines.The picture shows what it looks like now.

```
console.log(path2gcode(svg).join("\n"));
```

[image]

I actually made the text look the same as Figure 2, but Figure 2 somehow skipped one more line. All, my question is why this problem occurs and how should I change it.

Comment: Some of your actual array entries contain newlines themselves and those newlines display different in your two methods.  It's unclear to me what you want to do about that or what exactly your question is.

Comment: What should I do if I need to arrange each row compactly without extra empty rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.join('\n')` you are essentially adding a newline to the end of each string, even ones that already have a new line. The answer depends on what you want to do, but to make it not print blank lines, you could do something like:

```js
console.log(path2gcode(svg).map(v => v.replace(/\n$/, '')).join("\n"));
```

^All that does, is checks each entry and removes a trailing `\n` if it has one.